# how can I join two very different table structures? No common keys

Tags: postgresql

For the purpose of good database design, I've never run into an issue like this, but we are currently changing systems and there is a new key system that will need to be merged in with the old. I can create a surrogate key, but it'll be a lot of effort to prevent duplicate keys at that point. A number of the fields will line up, but no records will match on their keys since the two systems will not overlap.

Lets say for example we have something like this....

Old Tables

```
ID | Field1 | Field2 | Field3
1  | asdfgh | asdfgh | asdfgh
2  | asdfgh | asdfgh | asdfgh
3  | asdfgh | asdfgh | asdfgh
```

New Table (with composite keys)

```
ID1 | ID2 | Field1 | Field3 | Field4
1   | 1   | asdfgh | asdfgh | asdfgh
2   | 2   | asdfgh | asdfgh | asdfgh
3   | 3   | asdfgh | asdfgh | asdfgh
```

I'd like an end result like this:

```
ID | ID1 | ID2 | Field1 | Field2 | Field3 | Field4
1  |     |     | asdfgh | asdfgh | asdfgh | 
2  |     |     | asdfgh | asdfgh | asdfgh | 
3  |     |     | asdfgh | asdfgh | asdfgh | 
   | 1   | 1   | asdfgh |        | asdfgh | asdfgh
   | 2   | 2   | asdfgh |        | asdfgh | asdfgh
   | 3   | 3   | asdfgh |        | asdfgh | asdfgh
```

This would be an ugly table, but it'll let me turn it into a composite across the three ID fields. How could I create this table from the two previous ones? Also, the fields can line up in any order.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What sql could I use to create a table from the two original tables to look like the last one?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se! Please go to dbfiddle.uk and construct a fiddle with your input data and give us your desired output from that input. Your problem is currently unclear.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [UNION ALL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/queries-union.html)

```
select id,null as id1,null as id2,field1,field2,field3,null as field4
from old_table
union all
select null as id, id1, id2,field1,null as field2,field3,field4
from new_table;
```

> Result:
>
> ```
> id    id1 id2 field1  field2  field3  field4
> 1         asdfgh  asdfgh  asdfgh  
> 2         asdfgh  asdfgh  asdfgh  
> 3         asdfgh  asdfgh  asdfgh  
>      1    1   asdfgh          asdfgh  asdfgh
>      2    2   asdfgh          asdfgh  asdfgh
>      3    3   asdfgh          asdfgh  asdfgh
> ```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2a36c5a315622a01aa284017b2847cf5)

Comment: any way to do this without a union? The fields on the second table will be prone to change and will require manual updates that'll make them prone to user errors.

Comment: @JohnSly The table structures must be well-known and definite. When the table structure changes then according SQL script or procedure must be created and applied. And all queries must be changed according to new structure. The only case when we can deal with an indefinite/unstable structure is the import of data obtained from an uncontrolled source. Of course, dynamic SQL exists - but such code is close to non-maintainable.